# How to fill in a dataframe with lists of vectors?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

I have a list of vectors `LIST1` as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 1 5

[[3]]
[1] 7 12 61 12
```

I also have another list of vectors `LIST2` :

```
[[1]]
[1] 32 12 51 12

[[2]]
[1] 51 11 1

[[3]]
integer(0)
```

My goal is to transform the two lists into a dataframe where each vector is a cell, so the dataframe will be consisting of two rows and 3 columns:

```
             V1               V2           V3
LIST1    1,2,3,4,5,6,7      2,3,1,5     7,12,61,12
LIST2    32,12,51,12        51,11,1        NA
```

This is my code so far:

```
    my_dataframe = data.frame(matrix(vector(),nb_of_lists,length(LIST1))
    
    list_all = list(LIST1,LIST2) # put both lists in one list
    n = length(LIST1) # LIST1 and LIST2 have the same length so it doesn't matter
    
    for(x in 1:nb_of_lists)
    {
       for(y in 1:n))
         {
            my_dataframe[x,y]= list_all[[x]][y]
         }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, I'm getting mostly this warning message:

```
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = list(c(L1, L2, L3, :
    replacement element 1 has 7 rows to replace 1 rows
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need columns of class list. Here is one method:

```r
out <- as.data.frame(mapply(function(x,y) list(x,y), LIST1, LIST2))
str(out)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1:List of 2
#   ..$ : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#   ..$ : int  32 12 51 12
#  $ V2:List of 2
#   ..$ : int  2 3 1 5
#   ..$ : int  51 11 1
#  $ V3:List of 2
#   ..$ : int  7 12 61 12
#   ..$ : int
```

A second (and a more efficient) solution:

```r
out <- data.table::setDF(Map(function(x,y) list(x,y), LIST1, LIST2))
```

Reproducible data (please share it yourself next time)

```r
LIST1 <- list(1:7, c(2L,3L,1L,5L), c(7L,12L,61L,12L)) 
LIST2 <- list(c(32L,12L,51L,12L), c(51L, 11L, 1L), integer())
```